# jQuery DateTimePicker prroblem when minDateTime is set

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

[image: Datetimepicker problem with minDateTime]

[image: Datetimepicker problem with minDateTime]

Hello everybody,
this is Mladen, and todays question is, how to solve that :)

As you can see on those images, i set minDateTime, on current time, and i rounded it to  ten minutes (exp. if time is 09:3x it would be 09:40). But the problem is with date time picker, because if it is current day (highlighted), it allows me to change minutes from 40-50, and when you change hour it is same (but ih should be 00-50minutes), but when you choose another/next day, time is ok, an you can choose it normally.

Thank you in advance.

Simplifid code:

```
 minDate: new Date("<?php  echo date('M d,Y 09:40'); ?>"),
```

Comment: where interesting, i have no idea